# Assigning a string to Perl substr?

Tags: perl, substr

I am looking at Perl script written by someone else, and I found this:

```
$num2 = '000000';
substr($num2, length($num2)-length($num), length($num)) = $num;
my $id_string = $text."_".$num2
```

Forgive me ignorance, but for an untrained Perl programmer the second line looks as if the author is assigning the string `$num` to the result of the function `substr`. What does this line exactly do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, (unlike say, Python, where strings, tuples are not modifiable in-place), strings can be modified in situ. That is what `substr` is doing here, it is modifying only a part of the string. Instead of this syntax, you can use the more cryptic syntax:

```
substr($num2, length($num2)-length($num), length($num),$num);
```

which accomplishes the same thing. You can further stretch it. Imagine you want to replace all instances of **foo** by **bar** in a string, but only within the first 50 characters. Perl will let you do it in a one-liner:

```
substr($target,0,50) =~ s/foo/bar/g;
```

Great, isn't it?

Comment: You can even use the negative position: `substr($num2, -length($num), length($num), $num)`

Comment: and since the substr extends to the end, it could be written just: `substr($num2, -length($num)) = $num`.  (as long as you know length($num) isn't 0)

Answer (score 6):

Exactly what you think it would do:

```
$ perldoc -f substr
```

> You can use the substr() function as an lvalue, in which case
>                  EXPR must itself be an lvalue.  If you assign something shorter
>                  than LENGTH, the string will shrink, and if you assign
>                  something longer than LENGTH, the string will grow to
>                  accommodate it.  To keep the string the same length, you may
>                  need to pad or chop your value using "sprintf".

Answer (score 2):

"Exactly", you ask?

Normally, `substr` returns a boring string (PV with POK).

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$_="abcd"; Dump("".substr($_, 1, 2));'
SV = PV(0x99f2828) at 0x9a0de38
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADTMP,POK,pPOK)
  PV = 0x9a12510 "bc"\0
  CUR = 2
  LEN = 12
```

However, when `substr` is evaluated where an lvalue (assignable value) is expected, it returns a magical scalar (PVLV with GMG (get magic) and SMG (set magic)).

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -e'$_="abcd"; Dump(substr($_, 1, 2));'
SV = PVLV(0x8941b90) at 0x891f7d0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (TEMP,GMG,SMG)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0
  MAGIC = 0x8944900
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_substr
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_substr(x)
  TYPE = x
  TARGOFF = 1
  TARGLEN = 2
  TARG = 0x8948c18
  FLAGS = 0
  SV = PV(0x891d798) at 0x8948c18
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (POK,pPOK)
    PV = 0x89340e0 "abcd"\0
    CUR = 4
    LEN = 12
```

This magical scalar holds the parameters passed to `susbtr` (TARG, TARGOFF and TARGLEN). You can see the scalar pointed by `TARG` (the original scalar passed to `substr`) repeated at the end (the SV at 0x8948c18 you see at the bottom).

Any read of this magical scalar results in an associated function to be called instead. Similarly, a write calls a different associated function. These functions cause the selected part of the string passed to `substr` to be read or modified.

```
perl -E'
   $_ = "abcde";
   my $ref = \substr($_, 1, 3);  # $$ref is magical
   say $$ref;                    # bcd
   $$ref = '123';
   say $_;                       # a123e
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like it's overwriting the last length($num) characters of $num2 with the contents of $num in order to get a '0' filled number.

I imagine most folks would accomplish this same task w/ sprintf()